# How to create @Query() for avg(column) for every n minutes?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, hql

I have a postrges query which does that but I cannot translate it into a spring @Query definition:

```
select AVG(price) as price,date_trunc('hour', created) + date_part('minute', created)::int / 5 * interval '5 min' as created from table_name where created between '2022-04-19 00:00:00' and '2022-04-19 23:59:00' group by created
```

I tried to use funcion() for date_trunc and date_part also tried to concat the two result insted of + sign but I couldn't cast it to int but it did not work and also seems unnecessarily complicated.

Also it would be nice to be able to dynamically add the minute part istead of the pre defined value.

Example data :

```
|price|created|
|100|2022-04-19 00:00:00|
|107|2022-04-19 00:01:00|
|109|2022-04-19 00:02:00|
|105|2022-04-19 00:06:00|
|97|2022-04-19 00:07:00|
|99|2022-04-19 00:08:00|
```

Expected:

```
|price|created|
|105.33|2022-04-19 00:00:00|
|100.33|2022-04-19 00:05:00|
```

TIA.

Comment: Please post sample data, as text - **no images**, and the expected results of that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [generate series](https://www.timescale.com/blog/how-to-create-lots-of-sample-time-series-data-with-postgresql-generate_series/) to create a set of timestamps then use those and you desired interval to create date time ranges ([tsrange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN)), and finally join the table on range containment. This of course requires you to specify the start time and stop time. At worst these will be min and max created respectively.

```
with build_ranges ( tm_range) as 
     ( select tsrange(dt, dt+interval '5 min', '[)') 
         from ( select generate_series( min_dt, max_dt, interval '5 min') 
                  from ( 
                        select date_trunc('hour', min(dateCreated) ) min_dt
                             , date_trunc('hour', max(dateCreated)) + interval '5 min'   max_dt
                          from tbl
                       )  s
              ) gs(dt)
     )
select round(avg(price),2), lower(tm_range) 
  from build_ranges
  left join tbl
    on (dateCreated <@ tm_range)
 group by lower(tm_range)
 order by lower(tm_range);
```

You can parameterize the same basic approach for any desired interval.The following does so with an SQL function. (However, instead of the just the `created` time it returns the complete interval).

```
create or replace function price_avg_over_interval( start_dt    timestamp 
                                                  , end_dt      timestamp 
                                                  , tm_interval interval 
                                                  )  
   returns table (adv_price      numeric
                 ,created_range  tsrange
                 ) 
  language sql 
as $$
    with build_ranges ( tm_range) as 
         ( select tsrange(dt, dt+tm_interval, '[)') 
             from ( select generate_series(  start_dt ,end_dt, tm_interval) ) gs(dt)
         )
    select round( coalesce(avg(price),0),2), tm_range 
      from build_ranges
      left join tbl
        on (dateCreated <@ tm_range)
      group by tm_range 
      order by tm_range ;
$$;
```

Since the above is a SQL function you should be able to extract just the SQL statement and parameterize it Spring Query. I unfortunately I do not know Spring.  
See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=aa6c207a12650b93047027aac7725f34). It contains both the above.